# How to figure out if a process with a certain process id exists in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to know how to determine if a certain process with a given process Id is still running using powershell, so that the command

```
 Stop-Process -Id $process_id
```

will not result in an error.

I already tried

```
(Get-Process).Id
```

, but I don't know how to search the list for my desired process id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
If (Get-Process -Id $process_id -Ea SilentlyContinue){
  Stop-Process -Id $process_id
}
```